# Curie temperature

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics

Does a ferrite core (or other material) have their magnetic characteristics changed when they reach curie temperature and goes below it (considering it does not suffer any mechanical damage from that) ? If so, is it normally sufficient to change the design of a component (transformer, inductor), or it is small (well this of course depends on design constraints and material).

My question is about the component being running only below the Curie temperature, so not to consider their state at or above the Curie temperature. To be more specific, is about using high temperature to get the glue out and open ferrite cores.

Answer (score 1):

Cores get into trouble if the core material reaches the Curie temperature. The material becomes paramagnetic instead of ferromagnetic, meaning your inductor or transformer isn't an inductor or transformer any longer - the change in material behaviour causes inductance to drop to insignificant levels. Essentially the high temperature causes the magnetic dipoles to go all asunder.

The effect reverses when the cores are cooled - operation at the Curie temperature doesn't permanently alter the magnetic characteristics of the core. However, operating hot (with the loss of inductance caused by the heating) can lead to circuit damage, both to the magnetic itself and to parts feeding to and from it - imagine replacing your magnetics with short-circuits and see what sort of fireworks you can end up with. Melted windings are common, as are blown power devices.

Because of this, from a design standpoint, it's important to ensure that the magnetic component *never* reaches a point where it loses its inductance. Once the critical point is reached, that loss of inductance leads to higher current, which leads to higher winding temperature, higher core temperature and a nasty positive feedback loop which can result in catastrophic failures with safety implications.

You can include safety overrides - like embedding a temperature sensor into/onto the magnetic to shut things down if it gets too hot, over-current shutdowns, cooling fan monitoring, etc. For robustness, you can also design your magnetics for high temperature operation (use Class-H rated materials, which are good up to 180°C) even if your maximum part operating temperature is 100°C. Why? When the product is safety-evaluated, those smart folks will come up with numerous ways to figure out what will cause those magnetics to reach their maximum temperature, and do those tests to see if the unit survives - or at least fails safely.

Some references: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) and [Magnetics Inc.](http://www.mag-inc.com/File%20Library/Product%20Literature/General%20Information/cg-06.pdf)

Comment: Impatient, are we? I don't live to answer questions on this site. I chime in when time allows, between a full-time job, part time studies and a full-time marriage.

Comment: Sorry I'm on the same, is just a convention that you wait a small type when post an question or an answer, as you should expect responses in the small time, this was on Meta somehow. Anyway no problem, I just remember one high rank never answering the comments, probably not you.

Comment: I have changed my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It depends quite a bit on what the material is.  Depending on the temperature it goes to above the Curie temperature and how it was originally fabricated, the magnetic and other properties may change somewhat.  Without knowing what type of transformer, what material, and what maximum temperature it's not possible to say more.  For an example, see [this article](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1576626).  The statement you quote above in bold is not universally true.

Comment: Thanks, what I quote in bold is from the Magnetics Inc. paper. I read the briefing of the document, I could not get it at all, they say that the core have some induced current during the process, what is not true in my case. I have updated the question maybe its more objective.